# I'm trying to Sign In with Google in Flutter, the problem is after filling the Sign In Credentials it doesn't move to next page, and returns to login

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to Sign In with google in Flutter, the problem is after filling the Sign In Credentials it doesn't move to next page, and returns to login page. Also it doesn't save any data in Cloud Firestore. But it adds that email login user into users Authentication field in Firebase. I tried this with different codes to solve this but nothing happens.
Following is the work I've done till now.

```
**Flutter Doctor:**

C:\Users\Nouma>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052], locale en-PK)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!

C:\Users\Nouma>


**pubspec.yaml dependencies:**

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^2.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  auth_buttons: ^1.0.1+4
  cloud_firestore: ^2.3.0
  firebase_storage: ^9.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.4
  firebase_analytics: ^8.1.2
  firebase: ^9.0.1

**users.dart class where GoogleSignIn function is called:**

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn=GoogleSignIn();

late String name;
late String email;
late String imageurl;

Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = await GoogleSignIn()
      .signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount!
      .authentication;
  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,

  );
      final UserCredential result = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
      credential);
  final User? firebaseUser = result.user;
  assert(firebaseUser!.email != null);
  assert(firebaseUser!.displayName != null);
  assert(firebaseUser!.photoURL != null);
  name = firebaseUser!.email!;
  email = firebaseUser.displayName!;
  imageurl = firebaseUser.photoURL!;

   final User? currentuser = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
   assert(firebaseUser.uid == currentuser!.uid);
   return 'SignInWithGoogle Succeeded: $firebaseUser';
  //return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
}

**google.dart class, here GoogleAuthButton with GoogleSignIn function  is called:**


import 'package:authentication/users.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auth_buttons/auth_buttons.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';



final auth=FirebaseFirestore.instance;
class Google extends StatelessWidget {
  const Google({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: GoogleAuthButton(darkMode: true,
          onPressed: (){
        signInWithGoogle().then((googlesignedin)
        {
          auth.collection('users').doc('auth').collection('GoogleUsers')
              .add({
            'email':email, 'image':imageurl, 'name':name,}).then((value){
            if(googlesignedin!=null)
            {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/homepage');
            }
          }
          ).catchError((e)
          {
            print(e);
          });
        }
        ).catchError((e)
        {
          print(e);
        }
        );
        })
          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Future loginGoogle({Function? success, ValueChanged<String>? fail}) async {
try {
GoogleSignInAccount?  googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
GoogleSignInAuthentication?  googleAuth = await googleUser!.authentication;
  final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth.idToken);
  final result = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

  if (!result.user!.emailVerified) {
   print('Login Cancelled');
  } else if (result.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser) {
    // CRAETE USER
    print('SUCCESSFULYY CREATED USER');
  } else {
    print('ALL READY EXISTS THE USER');
  }
} catch (e) {
 print(e.toString());
}
```

}

##################################################################################
I HAVE MADE THAT FUNCTION FOR GOOGLE SIGN IN WITH NULL-SAFETY PACKAGES I HOPE IT WILL HELP YOU BROTHER

Comment: @ahmad mohammad abdilkadir bro,first of all thanks for the work you done for me, and second the issue is the same, it didn't work ,at Console it show the message 'SUCCESSFULYY CREATED USER' and also 'ALL READY EXISTS THE USER'. but the data doesn't go to Firestore and the app doesn't move to next page as well. Please check the Google.dart code which I uploaded in my question, maybe I've made a mistake there which I'm not able to see.

Comment: Did you add firebase json file into your project pro and also did you checked that you enabled gmail in the firebase auth ?

Comment: Bro the user information will go into the firebase  authentication not the firestore i hope you understood

Comment: Yes I added json file,and gmail is also enabled.

Comment: why it won't go into firestore, I've created the instance of firebasefirestore.